# MySQL - Non-Existent Tables Query

Tags: mysql, left-join

Currently, I have some common tables created and waiting for their respective `SELECT` queries. (Including their `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` instances)

I've run into occasions when a Table rarely needs to exist for some databases, but for others it will.

```
SELECT c.fname, c.lname, c2.colname  
FROM `tbl_cus` c 
 LEFT JOIN `tbl_cus_optional_data` c2 ON c.cusid = c2.cusid 
WHERE 1
```

`tbl_cus_optional_data` will exist on some databases, while others will not.
When a database table does not exist `MySQL` will throw an error, and the query stops, as expected.

Is there way to indicate inside the query if one of the `LEFT JOIN` tables does not exist, ignore it and any columns in the SELECT portion.

I'm probably searching for a unicorn here, but I get surprised by database capabilities often enough.

Comment: No. Either create an empty table or put a select around that query checking `information_schema.tables`

Comment: As solution you can use dynamic query in conjunction with information schemes.

Comment: Create all the tables in all the databases.  Simply don't put any rows in the tables that are not needed.